# Ukrainian citizen traveling to U.S.A with a connecting flight in Helsinki

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, ukrainian-citizens

My friend was turned away at the airport in Kiev. To catch a connecting flight to Helsinki, Finland.
To final destination new York...was told she needed shengen visa.....Even though she has a U.S. Visa

Comment: Is there any question involved? See [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)

Comment: OK but what's your question?

Answer (score 3):

The question, it it's a real question, might be lacking sufficient details (such as connecting flights being not in a single ticket?), but here is the [official information](http://visa.finland.eu/Ukraine/English/transit_airport.html) (there is also [Russian](http://visa.finland.eu/Ukraine/Russian/transit_airport.html) and other versions there):

> #### Overview
>
> Category applies to travellers who are transiting through Finland to a non-Schengen country. A list of nationalities who require a transit visa is determined in the Visa Code and can be found [here](http://visa.finland.eu/Ukraine/English/pdf/transit%20visas%20english.pdf). **Ukrainian nationals do not require a transit visa**. An applicant will have to provide evidence that he/she falls under this category.

See also:

- [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)